# How to search by ID an OBJ with Spring MVC and Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Im learning Spring MVC and Thymeleaf, currently I can make a page to create an OBJ and save it in my DB, also i can make a list of all of the obj and show it on the page.

What im trying to do is to be able to introduce and id in the page and search the matching id OBJ and show it on screen.

***This is my Entity:***

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
int dni;
String name;
String surname;


public int getDni() {
    return dni;
}
public void setDni(int dni) {
    this.dni = dni;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}
public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}
```

***This is my Repository:***

```
package com.demolorenzo.user;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
    List<User>findAll();
    List<User>findByName(String name);
    List<User>findByDni(int dni);
    
}
```

***And my Controller:***

```
package com.demolorenzo.user;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userrepo;
    
    
    @GetMapping("/Home")
    public String userForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "Home";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/Home")
    public String userSubmit(@ModelAttribute User user, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        userrepo.save(user);
        return "users";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/search")
    public String searchForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "search";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/search")
    public String searchSubmit(@ModelAttribute User user, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", userrepo.findByDni(user.getDni()));
        return "users";
    }
    
    
}
```

***This is the View (/search):***

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/search}" th:object="${user}" method="post">

      <p> DNI: <input type="number" th:field="*{dni}"/> </p>

      <p> <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>   
        
    </form>
```

***And the last View (/users):***

```
<h1>Result</h1>
    <p th:text="'Dni: ' + ${user.dni}" />
    <p th:text="'Name: ' + ${user.name}" />
    <p th:text="'Surname: ' + ${user.surname}" />
    <a href="/Home">Submit another message</a>
```

***And this is the error im getting:***

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'dni' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view is trying to access the `dni` property of the `user` object:

```
<p th:text="'Dni: ' + ${user.dni}" />
```

However, in the controller, you are doing:

```
@PostMapping("/search")
public String searchSubmit(@ModelAttribute User user, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", userrepo.findByDni(user.getDni()));
    return "users";
}
```

You are adding the result of the `userrepo.findByDni()` method as `user`. But that method returns a `List<User>`, not a single user.

So `user` in the view is a `List<User>` which obviously has not `dni` property.

You should probably update the controller method to put the result of the repository method in a variable `users` for example. And use `th:each` to iterate over those users.